# React Higher Order Component not rendering passed component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, higher-order-components

I'm writing a HOC in react to handle the heavy lifting of some scroll functionality. I'm having a hard time getting the component to render at all. I keep getting this error:

```
warning.js?d9a2:33 Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
```

I stripped it down to the most basic pieces of the HOC and I'm still getting this error. Here's my code:

This is the HOC itself:

```js
import React from 'react';

const withOnScreenMonitor = WrappedComponent => {
    return class OnScreenMonitor extends React.Component {
        render(){
            return (
                <WrappedComponent/>
            )
        }
    }
};

export default withOnScreenMonitor;
```

This is how I use it in one of my views:

```js
import withOnScreenMonitor from "../global-elements/OnScreenMonitor";

render(){
  //// other code
  
  const ComponentWithOnScreenMonitor = withOnScreenMonitor(<div>test</div>);
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div>
      /// other components
      </div>
      <ComponentWithOnScreenMonitor/>
    </Fragment>  
  )
}
```

And I keep getting this error. Am I missing something in how I set up this HOC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your HOC needs a component to render and not a JSX element. Also you must take out the static content out of render method. You can simply create a function component and use it like

```
import withOnScreenMonitor from "../global-elements/OnScreenMonitor";
const ComponentWithOnScreenMonitor = withOnScreenMonitor(() => <div>test</div>);
render(){
  //// other code

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div>
      /// other components
      </div>
      <ComponentWithOnScreenMonitor/>
    </Fragment>  
  )
}
```